# Writing a memory scanner in C#

Tags: c#, windows

I'm trying to make a memory scanner in C#. I heard that I need the API functions `WriteProcessMemory` and `ReadProcessMemory`.

I called them :

```
 [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(
        IntPtr hProcess,
        IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
        byte[] lpBuffer,
        UInt32 nSize,
        ref UInt32 lpNumberOfBytesRead
    );

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(
        IntPtr hProcess, 
        IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
        byte[] lpBuffer,
        uint nSize,
        out UIntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
```

All the examples for memory scanners I found on Google were very hard to understand. I've read a lot of articles saying that to find value addr you need to search at any memory byte. Now I need to get the program to open the process for reading and writing from memory.

Can I do that with `GetProcessByName`?

Comment: Short answer: yes. Long answer: yes.

Comment: [Read and try to understand the source of this project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/sojaner_memory_scanner.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, like so:

```
Process[] process = Process.GetProcessesByName("cmd");
byte[] memory = new byte[255];
uint bytesRead =0;
bool succes = ReadProcessMemory(
             process[0].Handle,  
             process[0].MainModule.BaseAddress , 
             memory , 
             (uint) memory.Length , 
             ref bytesRead);
```

You have to check if success is true. If not you have read nothing.

Comment: man another question, i dont need to check if process is working. i wanna open the process to the proggram for later read and writing

Comment: @user1124295 Any running process with the name cmd is 'opened' by this code sample and ready for later reading and writing. So you can go from here. I tried to explain that calling ReadProcesMemory might return false in case you provide it with a memory adress that is not in a valid range for the process where you read the memory from. Good luck with your effort.